# How to plot nonlogarithmic x-axis scale using drm package?

Tags: r, drm

I am using the drm package to plot a dose response curve:

```
> dput(virus_titration)
structure(list(virus_volume = c(0L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 20L, 40L), 
    fluorescent_perc = c(0.59, 34.87, 49.79, 70.41, 77.47, 86.88
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

I am using the following code to plot:

```
model <- drm(fluorescent_perc~virus_volume, data=virus_titration, fct=W1.4(names = c("Slope", "Lower Limit", "Upper Limit", "ED50")))

plot(model, xlab="Virus Volume (uL)", ylab="Fluorescent Percentage", type='all',lty=1, lwd=2)
```

This is giving a logarithmic x axis scale, but I would like a non logarithmic scale. Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/drc/html/plot.drc.html) you could specify an empty string to `log` to get the original axis:

> a character string which contains '"x"' if the x axis is to be
> logarithmic, '"y"' if the y axis is to be logarithmic and '"xy"' or
> '"yx"' if both axes are to be logarithmic. The default is "x". The
> empty string "" yields the original axes.

Here some reproducible code:

```r
library(drc)
model <- drm(fluorescent_perc~virus_volume, data=virus_titration, fct=W1.4(names = c("Slope", "Lower Limit", "Upper Limit", "ED50")))

plot(model, xlab="Virus Volume (uL)", 
     ylab="Fluorescent Percentage", 
     type='all',lty=1, lwd=2,
     log = "")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I'd also like to get the value for virus volume which equates to fluorescent percentage of 30 and display the result on the graph? how is this possible? thanks